# Connecting to SQL Azure from Azure VM - internal IP or public VIP

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I have an SQL Azure database and Azure Virtual Machine with an application connecting to the database.

- They are in the same datacenter and under the same Azure
  subscription.
- I added public virtual IP of the virtual machine to the list of
  allowed IP addresses in the server configure page of management
  portal.
- Windows Azure Services are marked "Yes" in the "Allowed Services"
  section.

When trying to connect, I receive exception: "Client with IP address 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to access the server.", where x.x.x.x is the internal IP of the VM. I am hesitant to use internal IP in an allowed IP rule. Shouldn't SQL Azure see public IP of the VM during connection?

Answer (score 2):

> I am hesitant to use internal IP in an allowed IP rule. Shouldn't SQL
>   Azure see public IP of the VM during connection?

The calls are being made through the internal network so never actually leave the data centre. Why not add a rule as follows to only allow internal calls by opening the following IP range on the Azure Database:

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255
```

In the above case you don't need to worry about a transient IP on your VM.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that any other VM inside the data center including other tenants would be able to connect to the database ? T

Comment: VIPs stand for Virtual IPs and are external, public, and metered. DIPs are internal, private, and load balanced. Azure provides an API to discover your DIPs – do not assume you know them because they are DYNAMIC IPs. Azure won’t let you see other DIPs inside the system. REFERENCED: http://blog.mccrory.me/2010/12/13/microsoft-azure-cloud-top-20-lessons-learned-about-msfts-paas/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try looking at the azure cmdlets that allow you to manage firewall rules by script. You could add a start up job to update a specific rule with the new IP the vm should it change do to a migration or reboot.

Specificially these powershell cmdlets:

- New-SqlAzureFirewallRule - Adds a new Sql Azure firewall rule to a
  server.
- Get-SqlAzureFirewallRules - Returns the firewall rules for
  the specified Sql Azure server.
- Remove-SqlAzureFirewallRule -
  Removes an existing Sql Azure fireall rule.

[Sql Azure Cmdlets](http://michaelwasham.com/tag/sql-azure-cmdlets/)